# x-editable for yii: concatenate fields on dropdown

Tags: php, yii, x-editable

I have a CGridView with an EditableColumn with a dropdown select defined like this:

```
array(
    'name'  => 'Id_department',
    'header'=> 'Department',
    'value' => '$data->Id_department ? Department::model()->findByPk($data->Id_department)->getConcatened() : "[click to edit]"',
    'class' => 'editable.EditableColumn',
    'editable' => array(
        'type'      => 'select',
        'model'     => new Employee(),
        'url'       => $this->createUrl('employee/update'),
        'source'    => $this->createUrl('department/getDepartments'),
        'params'    => array('YII_CSRF_TOKEN' => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken),
    ),
);
```

with this action in the controller:

```
public function actionGetDepartments(){
    $models = Department::model->findAll();
    echo CJSON::encode(Editable::source($models, 'Id_department', 'Name'));
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

This code builds the dropdown select with the **Name** attribute as the literal the user see on each option.

The think is that I have to show various attributes, not only one, so I tried to put a function call to a function that concatenates that fields in a single String in the source() function, but it doesn't works:

```
Editable::source($models, 'Id_department', concatenate())
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution (not the best one, obviously, but useful by the moment).

Basically, what I'm doing is adding a new attribute called `$concatenate_field` on the model and putting in it all I need. Then, I can use that field on the function call.

```
public function actionGetDepartments(){
    $models = Department::model->findAll();
    foreach($models as $model){
        $model->concatenated_field = $model->getConcatened();
    }
    echo CJSON::encode(Editable::source($models, 'Id_department', 'concatenated_field'));
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

I'm still looking for a better way to do it, but by the moment it works.